# Set cookie to change Bootstrap Menu

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, cookies

I have an HTML website, developed using bootstrap.

Basically I have a landing page that goes to either a white page, or a black page. On the white page, the menu is white, and on the black page the menu is black.

Depending on which page the user visits, they will see either a white menu, or a black menu.

I want to set up a cookie to remember which page they have selected to go to (White or black), and change the navbar and logo (put in a div id="black" or div id="white" )

This is my first time ever working with cookies, so I have no Idea how to call the cookie from another page, or how to change the div.

This is my code so far to set the cookie in the white page:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.cookie="menu=white";
}
</script>
```

Code to set cookie in black page:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
document.cookie="menu=black";
}
</script>
```

When users go to the next page, how do I call the value of the cookie, and change to the relevant menu, depending on the value of the cookie?

Some guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT : ANSWER**

I found the answer, thanks to Praveen.

On my landing pages, I set the cookies to either black or white, as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// set cookie
$.cookie('menu', 'black');
//alert( $.cookie("menu") ); --> to see that the cookie has been set
});
</script>`
```

Changing black to white for the white menu.

On the page that needs to read the cookie and hide the div that needs to be hidden, I do it as follows:

```
<script>
if ($.cookie('menu') == 'black')
{
$('.cookiewhite').hide();
}
if ($.cookie("menu") == 'white')
{
$(".cookieblack").hide();
}
// alert( $.cookie("menu") );
</script>
```

I then named my div's for the menu's div class="cookieblack" or div class="cookiewhite"

I hope this can assist other people too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : ANSWER

I found the answer, thanks to Praveen.

On my landing pages, I set the cookies to either black or white, as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
// set cookie
$.cookie('menu', 'black');
//alert( $.cookie("menu") ); --> to see that the cookie has been set
});
</script>`
```

Changing black to white for the white menu.

On the page that needs to read the cookie and hide the div that needs to be hidden, I do it as follows:

```
<script>
if ($.cookie('menu') == 'black')
{
$('.cookiewhite').hide();
}
if ($.cookie("menu") == 'white')
{
$(".cookieblack").hide();
}
// alert( $.cookie("menu") );
</script>
```

I then named my div's for the menu's div class="cookieblack" or div class="cookiewhite"

I hope this can assist other people too.

Comment: It is not a good idea to unaccept if the work is good. But still, you may consider giving a vote up to the answer that helped you. I will feel much better to help others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since you are a newbie for cookies, you can get the help of a plugin called [**`jQuery.cookie`**](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie). Whatever you need to do, you have done, is taken care perfectly cross browser by this plugin.

To create a cookie, you need to do something like this:

```
$.cookie('menu', 'blue');
```

Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:

```
$.cookie('menu', 'blue', { expires: 7 });
```

Create expiring cookie, valid across entire site:

```
$.cookie('menu', 'blue', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

Read cookie:

```
$.cookie('menu'); // => "blue"
$.cookie('something'); // => undefined
```

The above code will see if the user is coming for the first time.

Read all available cookies:

```
$.cookie(); // => { "menu": "blue", "...remaining": "cookies" }
```

Delete cookie:

```
// Returns true when cookie was found, false when no cookie was found...
$.removeCookie('menu');

// Same path as when the cookie was written...
$.removeCookie('the_cookie', { path: '/' });
```

***Note:*** when deleting a cookie, you must pass the exact same path, domain and secure options that were used to set the cookie, unless you're relying on the default options that is.

Comment: Thank you for the info Praveen, I have been able to set the cookie to white. Can you perhaps assist with how to get the cookie from the next page and change the div depending on the value of the cookie?

Comment: @Spiral57 It is the process of "Read cookie". See above! :D